# "Unresolved attributes found when constructing LocalRelation", can somebody explain?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as

```
+---+---+---+---+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |
+---+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I convert two `columns` as `structs` by doing the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = myDF.withColumn("colA", struct($"A", $"B"))
  .withColumn("colB", struct($"C".as("A"), $"D".as("B")))
```

the `dataframe` and `schema` are

```
+-----+-----+
|colA |colB |
+-----+-----+
|[a,b]|[b,c]|
+-----+-----+

root
 |-- colA: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colB: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to combine both `struct` columns into one column, so I do

```
df.select(array(struct($"colA.A", $"colA.B"),struct($"colB.A", $"colB.B")).as("Result"))
```

which gives correct `dataframe` and `schema` as

```
+--------------+
|Result        |
+--------------+
|[[a,b], [b,c]]|
+--------------+

root
 |-- Result: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
```

I could get the same result by doing

```
df.select(array(struct($"A", $"B"),struct($"C".as("A"), $"D".as("B"))).as("Result"))
```

Now, if we look at the whole process, we have

```
$"colA" == struct($"A", $"B") == struct($"colA.A", $"colA.B")
```

and

```
$"colB" == struct($"C".as("A"), $"D".as("B")) == struct($"colB.A", $"colB.B")
```

**BUT**

when I do

```
df.select(array($"colA", $"colB").as("Result"))
```

I get the following error

> > requirement failed: Unresolved attributes found when constructing LocalRelation.
> >     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Unresolved attributes found when constructing LocalRelation.
> >         at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LocalRelation.(LocalRelation.scala:50)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$33.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1402)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$33.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1398)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
> >     .......
> >     ........

What is the meaning of the error and how should I correct?